# Continuous Integration: Test With Gulp + Codeship (gulp-jasmine)

Tags: gulp, codeship

When I run my back-end test, codeship mentions that nothing is returned:

```
13 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0 seconds
[16:31:49] Finished 'testBECodeship' after 5.34 s

This command didn't output anything for for a while, thus we stopped it. If the error is on our end please inform us so we can help you to fix this.
```

Gulp Code:

```
gulp.task('testBECodeship', function () {

  return gulp.src(paths.specs + '/backend/**/*.spec.js')
    .pipe($.jasmine({verbose: true}));
});
```

I also could use just jasmine but I have also front-end tests run with gulp, which require more configuration. Also it would be nice to have the same on my dev. systems as on the CI-System.

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy Andi, Marko from the Codeship crew here. We have seen some issues with running `jasmine` via Gulp as it seems the plugin will wait for changes to the files and not exit cleanly. Running `jasmine` directly without Gulp will work though!